# Primefaces AccordionPanel Filter

Tags: jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

On [Primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/) they have a search input on the left menu.  The menu looks to be an accordion panel and every key up triggers some kind of ajax to filter out the accordion tabs.

How did they accomplish this?  I looked through their show case but only saw similar example for DataTable and not any for AccordionPanel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After downloading Primefaces `showcase-5.0.war`, I looked at the `template.xhmtl` and found Primefaces was using jQuery UI to accomplish the search and the accordion menu.